# How to load data into Ext.tree.TreePanel (not through ajax)

Tags: extjs3

in example here
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.tree.TreePanel

i can see property `dataUrl: 'get-nodes.php',`

but how i can change data from inside my code? there is no `store` property or `setSource` method

`EDIT:`

as i found, one of the possibilities is to create my own `Ext.tree.TreeLoader` that would have `setSource` method and use it instead of default

maybe there is more variants?

`EDIT:`

seems there is already a solution for this

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?4595-Creating-Ext.tree.TreePanel-from-static-JSON-data-in-one-shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there is already a solution for this

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?4595-Creating-Ext.tree.TreePanel-from-static-JSON-data-in-one-shot